# Write an algorithm to return an array such that every number k from 1..n is occurring exactly twice and is k distance apart from its replica

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This question was asked in an interview.

For a given integer n >= 3 return an array of size 2n such that every number k from 1 to n is occurring exactly twice and every number and its repetition is separated by a distance equal to the number.

Function signature:

```
int* buildArray(int n)
```

For example, for n = 3:

```
3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2
```

Number `2`: 1st position 3 and 2nd position 6, so distance 6 - 3 - 1 = 2.
Number `3`: First `3` at position 1 and 2nd `3` at position 5, so distance 5 - 1 - 1 = 3.

For n = 4:

```
4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2
```

Comment: Isn't there a programming puzzles website somewhere?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Suggest me anything similar to stackoverflow, though I  think its 'okay' to ask algorithm question and have been asked in the past too. If you want, give it a try, or just ignore.

Comment: XOR all elements and if the result is 0, all the elements in array present twice.

Comment: @user3 Please reread the question, you need to build such array which is of size 2n and numbers from 1..n are all repeated exactly twice and every k is k distance apart its repetition.

Comment: @LalluMishra Algorithm questions are indeed acceptable and on-topic, however on StackOverflow, there is also the requirement that you demonstrate that you attempted to solve the problem first, and indicate where you're having difficult, or what your confusion or question is. Otherwise, its difficult to determine when a person is not merely attempting to have work done for them. Since this question is about a programming challenge, its probably better suited to the [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Langford's problem/sequence.

There is a topic about the same problem on SO with implementation already.
[Langford sequence implementation Haskell or C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809712/langford-sequence-implementation-haskell-or-c)

Answer (score 5):

This is an [exact cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), which you can solve with [Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X). (And it's a nicer, simpler example than Sudoku.) You have the following constraints:

- each number must be used exaclty twice and
- each slot in the array can only be occupied by one number

For your problem with *n* = 3, you get the following matrix:

```
     [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]  1   2   3
     --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
#0    X       X               X
#1        X       X           X
#2            X       X       X
#3                X       X   X

#4    X           X               X
#5        X           X           X
#6            X           X       X

#7    X               X               X
#8        X               X           X
```

The columns `[x]` mean that slot `x` is used; plain `x` means that the digit `x` has been placed. The rows #0 to #3 describe the possible placements of ones, #4 to #6 the placements of twos and #7 and #8 the twi possibilities to place the threes. This will yield the two (mirrored)  solutions:

```
2 3 1 2 1 3     (#2 + #4 + #8)
3 1 2 1 3 2     (#1 + #6 + #7)
```

Not all *n* yield solutions, there are no solutions for 5 and 6, for example.

Answer (score 3):

It's NP-complete problem.

However, it can be fairly easily coded-up using recursion and [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), making it suitable solution for an interview. It's similar to, for example, [N queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) backtracking solution (which was my inspiration).

Ready-to-run code in Java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;    
public class Test {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 3; i < 13; i++) {
            int[] answer = buildArray(i);
            if (answer[0] != 0) {
                System.out.println(i + " " + Arrays.toString(answer));
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[] buildArray(int n) {
        int[] answer = new int[2 * n];
        put(answer, n); // start with placing n, later (n - 1), (n - 2), ..., 1
        return answer;
    }

    private static boolean put(int[] answer, int k) {
        for (int i = 0; i + k + 1 < answer.length; i++) { // try every posiiton
            if (answer[i] == 0 && answer[i + k + 1] == 0) { 
                answer[i] = k;
                answer[i + k + 1] = k;
                if (k == 1) {
                    return true; // we found a solution, escape!
                }
                if (put(answer, k - 1)) {
                    return true; // we found a solution, escape!
                }
                answer[i] = 0;   // step back and erase this placement
                answer[i + k + 1] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false; // still not full solution, continue
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
3 [3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
4 [4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2]
7 [7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 1]
8 [8, 3, 7, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1]
11 [11, 6, 10, 2, 9, 3, 2, 8, 6, 3, 7, 5, 11, 10, 9, 4, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 1]
12 [12, 10, 11, 6, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 4, 6, 5, 10, 12, 11, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Are you sure it is NP complete?  I find it hard to see how given an algorithm to solve this problem you would be able to solve a different NP-complete problem?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Good doubt. But yes, it is NP complete. "Finding all Langford sequences is equivalent to solving an instance of the exact cover problem, Knuth [Knu08] => NP-complete". From slide 13 of [this](http://www.epcl-study.eu/content/phdws12/presentations/nguyen-phdws12.pdf) presentation.