# Array Constraint Satisfaction

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, constraints

> Given a range of number 1 through N, where N >=3. you have to take an
>   array of length 2N and place each number ( from the range 1 to N)
>   twice. such a that the distance between two indexes of a number is
>   equal to the number. example
>
> N=3
>
> ( 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 )

The solution I'm thinking of is as follows:

1. Generate every permutation array of the range of numbers, ex: {1,2,3|, {3,2,1}, {2,1,3}, etc.
2. For each permutation array, run the following functions:

   ```
   foreach(int number : permutationArray){
       addToResultArray(number);
   }

   addToResultArray(int toBeAdded){
       for(int i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++){
           //-1 implies the resultArray is empty at that index
           if(resultArray[i]==-1 && resultArray[i+toBeAdded+1]==-1)
               resultArray[i] = toBeAdded;
       }
   }
   ```
3. If the above functions do not cause an out of bounds exception, you have a valid solution.

I do not think this solution is very good. Does anyone have something better?

Comment: `Does anyone have something better?` Yes, take a pen and a paper, build valid results for `N=3` til `N=6` or `N=7` and find the pattern behind that assignment. Then rebuild that pattern in your code.

Comment: I'm not convinced such an arrangement exists for arbitrary n.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write an algorithm to return an array such that every number k from 1..n is occurring exactly twice and is k distance apart from its replica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933966/write-an-algorithm-to-return-an-array-such-that-every-number-k-from-1-n-is-occu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be viewed as a constrained problem: you have `2*N` variables `V={v1,v2,...,v2n}` (representing the array indices) each variable has `[1,2,..,N]` possible values under the constraints:

1. Every value is assigned to exactly two variables.
2. The distance between variables with the same value equals the value itself.

An assignment is a mapping from the set of variables to their possible values. For example `[v1=1,v2=3,v3=5]` is an assignment for `v1,v2` and `v3`. A given assignment is ***consistent*** if it satisfies the constraints. An example to inconsistent assignment is `[v1=3,v2=1,v3=3]`

An assignment is complete if its cardinality equals the variables size (i.e. `2*N`). Otherwise it is a partial assignment. Clearly, our goal is to have one or more complete consistent assignment (a.k.a solution).

So the problem is basically a *backtracking* search problem. In particular, we have an ordering over the variables. Each time we assign a value to the current variable. If the value makes the current assignment inconsistent, we *backtrack*.

Your approach is actually a [generate-and-test](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_77.html) which is inefficient.  Generating all solutions and counting them is hard problem in general. In most of the cases, we are looking for one solution.

*Here is the interesting part: there is a much more efficient way to do this by propagating the values and detecting backtracking sooner (see [constraint propagation](http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/constraints/propagation.html)).*