# How to optimize my Langford Sequence function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

This is my code for making a Langford Sequence out of an array of pairs of numbers (112233 -> 312132).  I wanted to write a recursive function, because I wasn't able to find one online anywhere as a self-improvement exercise with algorithms.  My question is, how do I optimize it?  Is there a way to apply dynamic programming to this and have a better time/space complexity with emphasis on time complexity?  My current Runtime complexity is O(n^2) and Space complexity of O(n).  Any sort of help in writing cleaner code is also appreciated.  Thanks.  Also, is this a P or an NP problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int arrLen = 8;
const int seqLen = 8;

bool langfordSequence(int * arr, int indx, int *seq, int pos);
int main() {

    int arr[] = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4};
    int seq[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    bool test = langfordSequence(arr, 0, seq, 0);

    if (test)
        cout << "Langford Sequence Successful: " << endl;
    else
        cout << "Langford Sequence Failed: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < seqLen; i++)
    {
        cout << seq[i] << " ";
    }   
    return 0;
}

bool langfordSequence(int * arr, int indx, int *seq, int pos)
{

    if (indx >= arrLen - 1) //this means we've reached the end of the array
        return true;

    if (pos + arr[indx] + 1 >= seqLen)  //if the second part of the number is off the array
        return false;

    if (seq[pos] == 0 && seq[pos + arr[indx] + 1] == 0)
    {
        seq[pos] = arr[indx];
        seq[pos + arr[indx] + 1] = arr[indx];
        if (langfordSequence(arr, indx + 2, seq, 0))    //the current pair is good, go to the next one, start from the beginning
            return true;
        else
        {
            seq[pos] = 0;
            seq[pos + arr[indx] + 1] = 0;
            if (langfordSequence(arr, indx, seq, pos + 1))
                return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (langfordSequence(arr, indx, seq, pos + 1))  //current position is no good, try next position
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: First idea that comes to mind after reading up on the problem is: if you can enumerate the hooked sequences for lower *n*, solving for higher *n* becomes a matter of seeing whether you can plug two elements into the right-size gap. A hooked sequence is one like 121_2 or 2_121. Either has a gap into which you can plug a 3 and get 312132 or 231213.

Comment: There’s also a symmetry in the problem space in that the reverse of any solution is a solution.

Comment: Are you sure your algorithm runs in `O(n^2)` time? If I understand your algorithm correctly, worst-case you try to put every input in every possible position, until you find a solution. That is `O(2^n)` running time...

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele you're right.  It is O(2^n), I'm still getting the hang of measuring the time complexity.  It feels tricky to find out the time complexity on recursive algorithms.  Ugh, this algorithm is so slow!

Comment: @Lorehead you mean instead of starting from first position again, keep track of the open positions and see if those work directly?  That had crossed my mind, but won't I still have to search through the array to find an open slot?  Maybe I can have another array that stores the open slots.  I.e. First element stores first open slot, second element stores second open slot, etc.  But I still won't be able to make it less than O(2 ^n) right?

Comment: You're gonna be interested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5812801/2095090 it's no C++ but I suppose you can read it still. Theoretically, that solution also takes exponential time worst case but due to the heuristic used the chances of picking a wrong position are minimized.

Comment: That’s not precisely what I meant, but my explanation will have to be an answer, even though I don’t currently have the opportunity to implement or test it.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s pseudocode for the idea I was referring to in my comments.  I haven’t searched to see who else has done something like this yet (because I like to solve things myself first) but someone else probably has priority.

Algorithm LANGFORD
Parameters N (largest element in the top-level, final sequence), M (largest element of the intermediate, hooked sequence).  At the top level, M = N.
Returns: A list of all sequences of length 2N such that each element j in 1..M appears exactly twice separated by exactly j elements and the position of the second M is less than N + M/2 + 1.  All other elements of the sequence are set to 0.

```
If M == 1 (base case)
  Let S' := []
  For i := 0 to N-2
    Let s' be the length 2N sequence containing the subsequence "101" starting at position i (counting from 0), and zero everywhere else.
    Insert s' into S'
  Return S'

Otherwise: (inductive case)
Let S' := []
Let S := LANGFORD(N,M-1)
For each s in S
  Let r := reverse(s)
  For i := 0 to floor(N - M/2 + 1)
    If s[i] == s[i+M+1] == 0
      Let s' be s with s'[i] and s'[i+M+1] replaced by M
      Insert s' into S'
    If r != s and r[i] == r[i+M+1] == 0
      Let r' be r with r'[i] and r'[i+M+1] replaced by M
      Insert r' into S'
Return S'
```

Running this algorithm for N = 4, we have initially M = 4 and recurse until N = 4, M = 1.  This step gives us the list [[10100000],[01010000],[00101000]].  We pass this back up to the M=2 step, which finds the hooked sequences [[12102000],[10120020],[20020101],[02002101],[00201210],[01210200],[20021010],[00201210],[20121000],[02012100]].  Passing these up to the M=3 step, we get [[30023121],[13120320],[13102302],[31213200],[23021310],[23121300],[03121320]].  Finally, we return to the top-level function and find the sequence [[41312432]], which also represents its symmetric dual 23421314.

Essentially, we're trying to fit each puzzle piece like "30003" into each potential solution, keeping in mind that the mirror image of any solution is a solution.  The time and space complexity are dominated by the combinatorial explosion of potential solutions for values of M around N/2.  It might be fast to store the sequences as byte arrays aligned to use vector instructions, and the lists as array lists (vector in C++, [sequence] in Haskell, etc.).